selecting the most appropriate statistical test for comparison of multiple independent variables belonging to two groups
I want to compare the drinking water chemistry of two areas.  A disease is prevalent in one area while the other area is almost free from this disease. I have measured the concentrations of 10 chemical compounds in equal number of drinking water samples from these two villages.  Therefore, I have two groups of drinking water, one group is linked to the disease and the other with no link to the disease. What would be the best statistical test to compare concentrations of chemical compounds from these two groups of samples?  Can I use multiple t-test (i.e. Welch's t-test)? If so, is a correction needed for alpha inflation? If not, would one-way ANOVA be more appropriate?

Multivariate Analysis of Variance (MANOVA) should do this. Whether this is "most appropriate" depends on how the data behave regarding model assumptions, which I of course can't know without knowing the data.
